# Object isn't recognized as part of collection

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to create a script which gathers puts elements from XML in a list and verifies that a specific object is a part of this list. Please find my script below:

```
class BaggageEntitlement{
    String allowancePieces
    String ruleType
    String ruleId
    String passengerNameRef
    String segmentNumber

boolean equals(BaggageEntitlement that) {
    return (
            this.allowancePieces.equals(that.allowancePieces) &&
                    this.ruleType.equals(that.ruleType) &&
                    this.ruleId.equals(that.ruleId) &&
                    this.passengerNameRef.equals(that.passengerNameRef) &&
                    this.segmentNumber.equals(that.segmentNumber)

        )
    }
}

ArrayList<BaggageEntitlement> expectedEntitlements = new ArrayList<BaggageEntitlement>()
ArrayList<BaggageEntitlement> actualEntitlements = new ArrayList<BaggageEntitlement>()

BaggageEntitlement segment1Entitlement = new BaggageEntitlement(allowancePieces : '2', ruleType : 'OVERRIDE', ruleId : '15483', passengerNameRef: '01.01', segmentNumber: '1')

def cbfNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml()).Body.CalculateBagFeesRS

def baggageEntitlementNode = cbfNode.AncillaryOffers.Itinerary.BaggageEntitlements

baggageEntitlementNode.EntitlementItineraryPart.each{
    def baggageAllowanceEntitlementNode = it.BaggageAllowanceEntitlement
    BaggageEntitlement baggageEntitlement = new BaggageEntitlement()
    baggageEntitlement.allowancePieces = baggageAllowanceEntitlementNode.MaxPieces.text().toString()
    baggageEntitlement.ruleType = baggageAllowanceEntitlementNode.@ruleType.toString()
    baggageEntitlement.ruleId = baggageAllowanceEntitlementNode.@ruleId.toString()
    baggageEntitlement.passengerNameRef = it.PassengerReference.@nameReferenceNumber.toString()
    baggageEntitlement.segmentNumber = airIdToSegmentNumber[it.SegmentReference.@segmentNumber.toString()]

    actualEntitlements.add(baggageEntitlement)

}
```

But after creating a collection, objects which are present in created collection aren't recognized as a part of collection. I've created the following piece of code to demonstrate this:

```
println "Is iterator in collection: ${actualEntitlements.contains(segment1Entitlement)}"
println "Is object equals (I) to iterator: ${actualEntitlements[0] == segment1Entitlement}"
println "Is object equals (II) to iterator: " + actualEntitlements[0].equals(segment1Entitlement)
println "Is 'allowancePieces' members are equal: " + (actualEntitlements[0].allowancePieces == segment1Entitlement.allowancePieces)
println "Is 'ruleType' members are equal: " + (actualEntitlements[0].ruleType == segment1Entitlement.ruleType)
println "Is 'ruleId' members are equal: " + (actualEntitlements[0].ruleId == segment1Entitlement.ruleId)
println "Is 'passengerNameRef' members are equal: " + (actualEntitlements[0].passengerNameRef == segment1Entitlement.passengerNameRef)
println "Is 'segmentNumber' members are equal: " + (actualEntitlements[0].segmentNumber == segment1Entitlement.segmentNumber)
```

And the console output for comparing object member by member is looks like:

```
Is iterator in collection: false 
Is object equals (I) to iterator: true
Is object equals (II) to iterator: true
Is 'allowancePieces' members are equal: true
Is 'ruleType' members are equal: true
Is 'ruleId' members are equal: true
Is 'passengerNameRef' members are equal: true
Is 'segmentNumber' members are equal: true
```

Could you tell me why my object isn't considered to be a part of collection though member by member comparison returns 'true' for every member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you did not override equals. You supplied your own equals method with a different signature. Override the correct equals method...

```
public boolean equals(Object o) { 
    ... your code here... 
}
```

...and the Collection will recognize your object, as by the Collection contract for [`Collection.contains(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

(This means the correct equals method and not any equals method. The parameter must be an object, otherwise it is a different equals method and will not help you.)

Having a convenient method like `boolean equals(BaggageEntitlement that)` may be nice for other purposes (though I doubt it), but this method won't be called since most other classes will expect an Object and not a "BaggageEntitlement". Equals is one of the basic methods of Object, so you should always override that instead of creating your own different version.